# Python Keyring error (87, 'CredWrite', 'The parameter is incorrect.')

Tags: python, python-2.7, py2exe, python-keyring, mercurial-keyring

I am using python 2.7 on 32 bit XP machine and keyring 3.1 library.Also tried with 3.3 keyring. 
In  `keyring.set_password("name", "value", "hundred")`
am getting **error (87, 'CredWrite', 'The parameter is incorrect.')**. 
Error occurs in both eclipse and through py2exe during exe making. 
My setup.py is

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
import time
setup(
    windows=['python.py'],
    options=dict(py2exe=dict(
        packages='keyring.backends',
    )),
)
time.sleep(2)
```

Answer (score 0):

32-bit XP doesn't have Windows Vault. Use an alternative like Win Crypto. From keyrings.alt.Windows import EncrpytedKeyring and then keyring.set_keyring(). You will need to set the backend file_path member too.